# Automatic MySQL table creation [user controlled]

Tags: php, mysql, transactions

firstly let me be very precise in my question:

Basically I am learning PHP and MySQL so working on a little project for myself. I am creating a website for me and my friends where we can keep track of money we owe each other. In particular for a big sum that would need to be returned in bits over a few months.  So anyone of us can start a 'record' where they give this record a name e.g. 'Car Expenses' and then they can add a transaction to this record every time they get any money back from the borrower of that big sum. This 'Car expenses' record will have some columns obviously including transaction ID, amount returned, and date etc (coming back to this bit shortly).

I know that I will definitely need two tables: 
1) USERS - where user's name and email address is stored for all of us; 
2) RECORDS - where a summary of all of our records (but not the transaction details relating to any record) is saved e.g. record-title, record-description, creation-time, last-updated-time, name of parties involved etc.

However, the problem is that I am not sure how would the third part of the system work where I will go into details of a particular record for showing all transactions on the record e.g. how much money has already been paid and on what date etc.

I was thinking of creating a new table for each individual record that is created by a user. 
In this table then I will have transaction-id, transaction-date, money-in/out, comments, and controls for editing/deleting any transactions will be in place.

In my view, the problem with this approach (creating a new table every time) is that giving each newly created table a user-defined name will be a challenge, plus executing an automatic query for designing new table for each extensive record could be very difficult.

PLEASE ADVICE, what would be the best approach for implementing this third part of the system, or any better ideas for the overall database design for my website. Thanks very much in advance.

Comment: You don't need a new table for each record, but one table for all records that references the user ids and record ids.

Comment: Thank you aynber, I thought it will be complicated to pick transactions from one record from within the same table and show them where there will be so many transactions from everyone

Comment: As long as you design the table correctly with user_ids and record_ids and correct indexes, it won't be hard to track. In fact, it would probably make it easier if you wanted to show total transactions with links to each record.

Comment: Will I need both, the user_id and record_id (probably as foreign keys) in transactions-table? Is that correct that it will help me to identify what record from which user a cetain transaction belongs to?

Comment: Yes. If you're looking to expand to more people, I'd recommend two user fields, one for the payer, and one for the payee.

Comment: That is actually a very good idea, thank you so much for your help aynber!

Answer (score 0):

In general, you never want to have too many tables in a database, and certainly not user-defined ones. Not only will it take up space, but it will be next to impossible to query from it.

What you should do instead is create a separate table for ALL transactions with the columns you listed, but an additional column that holds the id of the user the transaction belongs to. That allows you to query easily via JOIN commands.

Comment: Thanks Hex37, I thought if I have more and more users in the future (family and friends lol who knows) then one table may reach it's limit with this many transactions from every one.

Comment: You'll almost never need to worry about that for SQL; Table searching in that scripting language is extremely efficient. It's almost the whole point of the coding language. At the most, for tables hundreds of thousands of rows large, you'll want to create a separate archive table for the oldest entries.

Comment: Thank you for being so elaborative. 
So how do you we know when a table has reached its limit and should be divided in an archive table, can we still query the same way from the archive table?

Comment: No trouble. In no uncertain terms, the size your table is only limited by the size of storage for your whole SQL database. It shouldn't have a hard 'limit' to work with. The best way to archive the data would be to add a timestamp column to your transactions table and create a [MySQL Event Scheduler](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36975795/how-to-periodically-archive-data-in-mysql) that archives all entries that are older than a certain timeframe. Also, yes, querying the archive is just as easy; it just moves data out of the way for the main table to be more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a simple, consistent schema to represent all the different elements in your system: Users and Exchanges. Picking names can be tricky, as you generally want to avoid using reserved keywords like "transaction".

Creating a new table for each exchange of money is absolutely wrong. The whole point of a relational database is to have a multitude of records stored in the same table where these may have simple relationships to other records. For example, an exchange references both a sender and a recipient by their respective "user" record identifiers.

In simple terms:

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  name VARCHAR(255),
  created_at DATETIME
);

CREATE TABLE exchanges (
  id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
  amount NUMERIC(12,2) NOT NULL,
  sender_user_id INT,
  recipient_user_id INT,
  created_at DATETIME
);
```

This is a very simple approach. A more robust solution uses a [ledger structure](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/67864/should-a-ledger-db-store-a-separate-line-for-each-side-of-a-transaction) where the exchange is broken down into two related but independent transfers between accounts.

Now if you want to know the balance owed:

```
SELECT sender_user_id, SUM(amount) FROM exchanges
  WHERE recipient_user_id=?
  GROUP BY sender_user_id
```

That will show you on a per-recipient basis how much money they're owed. So long as you represent "paying back" as a negative amount sent then the values should zero out. A ledger does this job better.

Comment: Really appreciate such a detailed reply mate, you'd probably complete this in like 15-20 mins LOL I have already spent weeks on it. The reason I wanted to add a third 'records' (summary) table was because, on dashboard of a user, I want to show them (may be on little cards) all the records they are part of.

Comment: Over your career as a developer you'll be asked to create a ledger system like this many times over. By the tenth time it becomes routine. The first time is pretty dizzyingly complicated. Summary records often become out of sync and for small amounts of data a quick `SUM()` is better than an unreliable summary record.

Comment: Nice one! will definitely look into ledger systems, thank you again for your time and shame that I can't do a thumbs up on any of the posts for being a newbie.